# Type {http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/}abstractBean is referenced but not defined

Tags: wsdl

Can someone please tell, what i am missing or doing wrong.
Below is my wsdl. I am trying to generate stubs from this wsdl but getting error as

```
java.io.IOException: Type {http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/}abstractBean is referenced but not defined.
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(SymbolTable.java:665)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:545)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

WSDL File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="DGI" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/" 
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/" version="1.0">
            <xsd:element name="getReleveRequest" nillable="false">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="SecurityHeader" type="tns:securityBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="AbstractHeader" type="tns:abstractBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="RequestData" type="tns:ArrayOfVignetteReq"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="getReleveResponse" nillable="false">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="tns:statusBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="SecurityHeader" type="tns:securityBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="AbstractHeader" type="tns:abstractBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="TotalAmountHeader" type="tns:totalBean"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="ResponseData" type="tns:ArrayOfVignetteResp"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getReleveRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getReleveRequest" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getReleveResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getReleveResponse" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="DGI">
        <wsdl:operation name="getReleve">
            <wsdl:documentation>Demande d’un relevé d’une ou plusieurs vignettes
                pour but de règlement ou de consultation de
                l’état de paiement d’une
                vignette. Le partenaire envoi ce message afin
                d’afficher au client
                les
                informations lui permettant de payer sa vignette.
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getReleveRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getReleveResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="DGISOAP" type="tns:DGI">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="getReleve">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/GETIDGI/getReleve" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="DGI">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:DGISOAP" name="DGISOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used example.org as namespace. Did you got it working without defining data types (abstractBean, securityBean, etc.)

Comment: Yes, If i am providing type as xsd:string instead of tns:abstractBean, I am able to generate the stubs.

Comment: Well, then the thing is that you can't generate a WS from WSDL without defining the types used. Unless others can provide an example where example.org can be used to define types in a contract, you can't use that namespace to "assume" types in a message

Comment: Can someone give some suggestion, how to get it to the work, by any type of update/modification.